# Windows create a directory alias?

Tags: windows-xp, shortcuts

How can I create an alias in Windows for a directory name so that I can type something like "MyDir" in the run box, and it go open that directory in explorer.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/34265/can-i-create-a-shortcut-to-a-windows-directory

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Browse to the folder you want to create the shortcut to
2. Right-click and select Sent to -> Desktop (create shortcut)
3. On your desktop rename the shortcut to whatever you want the alias to be
4. Move that shortcut to C:\Windows

Any file, folder, or shortcut you place in C:\Windows will be accessible from Start -> Run or any explorer window.

Comment: shortcut isn't the same as alias

Comment: Try it, it works.  It's the same thing as Ryan's solution but a hell of a lot easier because you don't have to open anything in notepad and type out all the paths.

Comment: Plus, you can always rename the shortcut itself for "alias"-like behaviour.  "C:\...\My Long Directory Name\" --> LongDir.lnk --> Start | Run | LongDir[Enter]

Comment: *> shortcut isn't the same as alias*   @JoelCoehoorn, in the context of the question it is.

Answer (score 4):

slightly OT:

have a look at Bayden System's **[SlickRun](http://www.bayden.com/Slickrun/)** (a free **floating command line utility** for Windows.), use "MyDir" as a *MagicWord* to open the folder in question.

Comment: I'll keep  this in mind for future stuff.

Comment: once you start using Slickrun, you may wonder how you ever managed without it. exactly what the doctors have ordered for keyboard junkies. :)

Comment: I concur: SlickRun should be a utility built into the O/S.  +1

Answer (score 3):

It's not the quickest way in the world, but this should work.

- Create a file called MyDir.cmd in any folder that's part of your PATH environment variable.  *C:\Windows* for example.
- Open that file in Notepad and type the following and then save it:

  start c:\path\to\mydir

Now you should just be able to run the command MyDir from anywhere and it will open explorer to that location.

Answer (score 2):

There's a utility for creating symbolic links in windows:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx?wt.svl=leftnav
e.g
junction c:\short-name "d:\my long dirname"

Comment: In Vista+, [`mklink`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194) is built-in. `;-)`

Answer (score 1):

1) Select the file or folder. 
2) Middle mouse click the file and drag to open space in open window, release. 
3) Select "Create Shortcuts Here" option.

Comment: "Middle mouse click"?  In Windows?  And what "open window" do you suggest that he drag it into?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want the `G:` drive to be mapped to your Google Drive. Here's how you'd do it:

1. open up command prompt
2. `subst G: "C:\Users\\*insert your userid here*\Google Drive"`

Then load up Task Scheduler and create a new task for it to run each time the computer starts up.

That's how I did it and it is working well so far, as I've only been using this substitute command today.

Anyone else, feel free to comment if you've had more extensive experience setting up a substitute drive to a cloud service and its results.

Answer (score 0):

Following @synetech,
the best option IMO is using `mklink /j shortcut origin`.

This will create a link that will also allow for reaching deeper paths, such as `origin/a/b/c` => `shortcut/a/b/c`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).