# Open specific folder/path in Explorer with run dialog

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, shortcuts, run-dialog

I want to set up a way to open some path with the run diaglog (<kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>). Let's say I type in `repo` and windows would open a explorer in `C:\foo\bar\svn`.

Is there a better way than creating a `repo.bat` like that?

```
@echo off
start explorer C:\foo\bar\svn
```

Comment: you can use text expansion as well.  for example, when you type :repo, it automatically expands to C:\foo\bar\svn. you can use it in run dialog or the address bar, plus you'll need only one file to store all rules. I would suggest autohotkey.

Comment: Duplicate? http://superuser.com/questions/49075/windows-create-a-directory-alias

Answer (score 0):

In addition to your batch file approach being the way i would solve this quickly, it's worth mentioning that launchy can do this for you as well.

http://www.launchy.net/

To me it has replaced the run dialogue as well as the start menu.